# python pandas select top 'n' from multiple sub group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame, with lets say 3 columns:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
A | x | p
A | x | q
A | x | r
A | x | r
A | y | s
A | y | t
A | z | u
B | x | q
B | x | r
B | y | t
```

I want to group this by the number of occurrences of the unique combination of the 3 columns & then select only the records per the top 2 (n) values of col3

So if the combination of (A, x) has 9 counts of p, 8 counts of q & 3 counts of r in col3 - then it should display only top 2 counts of col3:

```
A | x | p | 9
A | x | q | 8
```

I have tried nlargest, head & some other options from other forums, but none of it works in sub groups - they only display the top n of the group as a whole

Comment: Your output does not match your input.

Comment: I have to say... I'm very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and then `groupby` by first and second level with [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3']
         .value_counts()
         .groupby(level=[0,1])
         .head(2)
         .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
  col1 col2 col3  count
0    A    x    p      9
1    A    x    q      8
2    A    y    s      1
3    A    y    t      1
4    A    z    u      1
5    B    x    q      1
6    B    x    r      1
7    B    y    t      1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].value_counts())
col1  col2  col3
A     x     p       9
            q       8
            r       3
      y     s       1
            t       1
      z     u       1
B     x     q       1
            r       1
      y     t       1
Name: col3, dtype: int64
```

**Setup**:

```
d = {'col1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'col2': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'x', 'y'], 'col3': ['p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'r', 'r', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'q', 'r', 't']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
   col1 col2 col3
0     A    x    p
1     A    x    p
2     A    x    p
3     A    x    p
4     A    x    p
5     A    x    p
6     A    x    p
7     A    x    p
8     A    x    p
9     A    x    q
10    A    x    q
11    A    x    q
12    A    x    q
13    A    x    q
14    A    x    q
15    A    x    q
16    A    x    q
17    A    x    r
18    A    x    r
19    A    x    r
20    A    y    s
21    A    y    t
22    A    z    u
23    B    x    q
24    B    x    r
25    B    y    t
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but this also displays the top 2 of the combination of the groups, instead of the count of the sub groups

Comment: @Ritu - I add input dataframe, `df (A, x) has 9 counts of p` means `9 rows A,x,p` ? Can you explain more?

Comment: In this example, since the top 2 records are itself the top of the entire dataset, so its getting displayed correctly - However, if lets say instead of A, x, q having 8 records, B, x, p had 8 records then it should display B,x,p instead, which is not happening